# Checking for viruses in uploaded files using ClamAV

Tags: java, strings

I have to check an uploaded file for anti-virus and if there is an exception, I have to give a message according to the exception to the users. e.g. if its a timeout, I would ask the user to try againg in a while.

**My first class, fileUpload is:**

```
public class FileUpload {

    //Message when no virus found.     
    private static final String NO_VIRUS_FOUND =  "No virus found";


    //More attributes and functions


    public void checkFile(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent comp, Object value) throws IOException {
          file = (Part) value;
          if (file != null) {
                  String antiVirusResult;    
                  antiVirusResult = FileCheckClass.checkVirus(getConfig(), file.getInputStream(), NO_VIRUS_FOUND);
                 if (!antiVirusResult.contains(NO_VIRUS_FOUND)) {

                     generateAntiVirusMessages(antiVirusResult);
                     throw new ValidatorException(msgs);
                 }
          }
     }

}
```

**My seond class, FileCheck class has a checkVirus() function:**

```
public static String checkVirus(FileConfig fileconfig, InputStream inputStream, String noVirusFound) {
        try {

            ClamAVClient cl = new ClamAVClient(fileConfig.getClamavHost(), fileConfig.getClamavPort(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);      

            if(ClamAVClient.isCleanReply(cl.scan(inputStream))){
                return noVirusFound;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while scanning file: ", e);
            return e.toString();
        }
        return noVirusFound;
    }
```

From the check virus function, i have to return a string so I pass `NO_VIRUS_FOUND` into it from the first class.

- Is it an acceptable practice to pass a string from one class to another just for the purpose of string comparison at the end. My fear is that if I define the strings separately in two class, change in one class would severely affect the output of the function in the other.
- Can there could be some improvements that some one can suggest to the above situation?

Comment: But let me know how did u test it The negative scenario ? How did u check the exception? Because antivirus don't allow to download a virus file in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. there seems to be logical falacy: what if `ClamAVClient.isCleanReply()` returns false but no exception is thrown? there is no else clause there, and `checkVirus` would return no virus found.
2. instead of returning `String`, why doesn't `checkVirus()` re-throw the exception? that way, it can also return a String of a virus name (or whatever is produced from `ClamAVClient`)
3. instead of passing the String, make it public. then any class can refer to it as `FileUpload.NO_VIRUS_FOUND`
4. better still, make an enum out of the constant. that way, you can add values to the enum (like `VIRUS_FOUND` ...)

though it is arguable, [Coding by exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_by_exception) is considered an anti pattern.  Exceptions should be reserved for error conditions, not as indicator that a virus  was found.

### EDIT:

with regards to the question how to implement pt 2:
First, I would create a custum exception that signifies a failed virus check

```
public class VirusCheckException extends Exception {
    public VirusCheckException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
    public VirusCheckException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
    // also rest of constructors...
}
```

then, instead of returning the exception message, throw the custom exception. the return value is freed to return more rich data from the scan (if possible):

```
public static String checkVirus(FileConfig fileconfig, InputStream inputStream, String noVirusFound) 
throws VirusCheckException {
    try {
        ClamAVClient cl = new ClamAVClient(fileConfig.getClamavHost(), fileConfig.getClamavPort(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);      

        Object response = cl.scan(inputStream);
        if (ClamAVClient.isCleanReply(response)) {
            return noVirusFound;
        } else {
            return ClamAVClient.getVirusName(response);  // assuming there is such...
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new VirusCheckException("Virus Found!", e);
    }
}
```

now you will have to catch that exception in the callng method and handle it:

```
public void checkFile(...) {
    try {
        antiVirusResult = FileCheckClass.checkVirus(getConfig(), file.getInputStream(), NO_VIRUS_FOUND);
    } catch (VirusCheckException e) {
        generateAntiVirusMessages(e.getMessage());
        throw new ValidatorException(msgs);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me how your 2nd point can be implemented?

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: in your 2nd point you mentioned 'instead of returning String' but ín your implementation you rethrow the exception and still use a string. anyways, it was very helpful. instead of passing the string from another class, i just return a 'boolean' to indicate virus check failed or successful.

Comment: Also, i don't need a custom exception in that case.

Comment: And thanks for pointing out the logical fallacy :)

Comment: Wondering where / which library the ClamAVClient is from?

Comment: See https://github.com/solita/clamav-java

Comment: Once I use this tool. My inputStream is lost. In my case what i do is . I scan the input stream that is coming in from http source and if that stream is free from virus. I am writing to file output stream. But now. Scanning is going on fine. But the file is created with 0Bytes. My InputStream is flushed. What to do?